# taking multiple strings from text boxes and entering them into a Checked List Box C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm creating a simple To-Do list application with Windows Forms and C# but I seem to have got stuck on a section and after a lot of research I cannot find anything to help me.

The form has 2 text boxes (1 where user can type the name of the item to do - title box and 1 where the user can type in a description if needs be - description box), 1 TrackBar (where user can slide the bar from 1 - 10 to select priority) and a dateTimePicker (where user can select a date and time that the item should be completed by).

So it would look like it does below.

New Task Title: *[  -- text box --   ]*

Task Description: *[   -- text box --   ]*

Priority: *[  --- trackbar ---  ]*

End Date: *{Date/Time Picker}*

I wondered how I could get all them four pieces of information and output them to a Checkedlistbox row, so the output would be for example:

*Groceries - Pick up groceries - 6 - 02/05/2015*

I'm still rather new to programming and all and just needed some help.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've given reasonable names to all the controls on your form ...

1. Go to the Form designer, and double click on your "Add" button.  This will create a Click event handler for the button.  Make sure your Click method look something like this:

   ```
   private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string newItem = String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}",
           titleTextBox.Text, 
           descriptionTextBox.Text, 
           priorityTrackbar.Value,
           endDateTimePicker.Value.ToShortDateString()
           );

       this.checkListBox.Items.Add(newItem);
   }
   ```

Comment: It's not producing errors, just one question, I have an 'Add' button which when pressed would need to input that data to the checklistbox, how would I do that? Not quite used to this language, sorry!